# Nextjs: Can I define different fallback values for parameters in getStaticPaths?

Tags: next.js

I generate a page with several parameters in Next.js with the function getStaticPaths().
Two of these parameters come from the database and therefore I want to set fallback to blocking there, as new elements may be added to the database.
However, I have another parameter that may only have one of several predetermined values, so I want to set fallback to false there.

Is there a way to define the fallback status more precisely?

My getStaticPaths() currently looks like this:

```
export async function getStaticPaths(){
    const res = await fetch(process.env.DATA);
    var fromDatabase = [];
    if(res.status===200){
        fromDatabase = await res.json();
    }
    var paths = [];

    predefinedValues.forEach(predefinedValue =>(
        fromDatabase.forEach(data => (
            paths.push({params: {
                dataId: data.id,
                dataName: data.name,
                predefinedValue: predefinedValue.name
            }, locale: 'de' })
        ))
    ));

    return {
        fallback: 'blocking',
        paths: paths
    };
}
```

This gives me pages for all data from the database, but for predefinedValue I can enter any string and get a page generated.